# Move model directly above -Z axis?

Tags: objects, object-mode

I have a model that is located in the negative x-axis. Is there an automatic method to move it directly to the 0 axis? Location is already applied so that doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: You can only do it if you put the origin at the bottom of the armature, as suggested by Chris, if you don't want that there is no way (that I know) to automatically put it above the axis

Answer (score 1):

you can select both bottom bones in edit mode -> shift-s -> cursor to selected, then object mode, select the armature > object-> set origin to cursor, then shift-s -> cursor to world origin -> then shift-s -> selection to cursor